# Web Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin" failed

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

In final stage to install **Magento2** **version 2.4** by the following command i got an error.

this is my command:

```
./magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost.com/magento2 --db-host=localhost --db-name=D --db-user=root --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

and after starting installing i got this error:

```
[Progress: 1011 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl':
[Progress: 1012 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin':
Running data recurring...Reading /var/www/html/magento2/bin/composer.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/magento2/var/composer_home/auth.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/magento2/bin/composer.json
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): hg branch
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): fossil branch list
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): fossil tag list
Executing command (/var/www/html/magento2/bin): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /var/www/html/magento2/var/composer_home/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/html/magento2/bin/vendor/composer/installed.json
Web Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin" failed; unable to load /var/www/html/magento2/bin/composer.lock.

[Progress: 1013 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_User':
[Progress: 1014 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
[Progress: 1015 / 1282]
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
```

and after the installation finished, i got this message:

```
Magento installation complete.
```

And after that should my address **http://localhost.com/magento2**  let me start working on magento2,
but when i go to my address, i got blank page.

I tried to resolved this error:

```
Web Setup Wizard installation of "magento/composer-root-update-plugin" failed; unable to load /var/www/html/magento2/bin/composer.lock.
```

by this command

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
```

but nothing happened, after my research there's no solution match this error.

please if there's anyone can help me with this problem?
i'll be grateful, and another problem is my address does not  working correctly, i got blank page.
maybe that error is the problem, really i don't know.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution i found is installed an old version of Magento (2.3,2.2,...), because its setup is wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this link: https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/issues/15

You can get more informations about your error and how you can solve it very well for Magento future version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use dockergento and install magento community eddition 2.3.4
https://github.com/ModestCoders/magento2-dockergento , if you still can't see any content on main page use developer mode

```
dockergento magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

or manually delete static content and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the package [magento/composer-root-update-plugin](https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin), so we could temporarily remove it. I hope the problem may be fixed in the future.

---

Go to Magento root folder, edit the `composer.json` file, delete the line contains `magento/composer-root-update-plugin`.

Then run command `composer update`.